# Change in numerical values and troubles for rescaling data

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, continuous-data, scales

Here is my problem, a step in the analysis that should be quick & easy, but...

I have very various scales in my data and need to rescale my variables to compare them more efficiently in a lmer as I have a mix of continuous and categorical variables.
I was trying to use the scale() function to do that, which requires my data to be a matrix.

```
mydata= as.matrix(mydata)
scale(mydata, center = F, scale = T)
```

returns the error : `Error in v^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`
Because, I thought, converting the table in a matrix doesn't always change it into numerical values, so I tried to rescale my column one by one after turning it into numerical values as follows :

```
mydata$var1 = as.numeric(mydata$var1)
scale(mydata$var1, center = F, scale = T)
```

But using as.numeric completely changed my values,e.g. from 0.2 to 170 or so (and rescaling doesn't change them at all). Consequently, doing a lmer() on these rescaled values return the error
`Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling`.

So my questions are :
1. Any idea why my numerical variable var1 is not considered as a number and fail to have the correct value when I try to fix it?

2. Should the scale function be working on a matrix, if my first problem was solved ? Would the categorical variables be a problem or just 'skipped' by the function?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Can you check if any of your variables were stored as factors? Running as.numeric() on a factor datatype will give you misleading results.